# Dots Animation Causing innerHTML Error in React Component

Tags: reactjs, innerhtml

I am trying to create a very basic loading animation inside a react component that displays while my API is loading. I found a solution that does what I want, but once my API is loaded and the component is no longer displaying, I start getting this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')"

I have read something about clearing the interval but couldn't figure it out.

Here is the component I built:

```
const LoadingData = () =>{
    var dots = window.setInterval(function() {
    var wait = document.getElementById("wait");
         if ( wait.innerHTML.length > 5 )
            wait.innerHTML = "";
        else 
            wait.innerHTML += ".";
        }, 200);
    return(
        <p>Loading<span id="wait">.</span></p>
    )
}
```

I also get a warning the "dots" is declared, but not used.  I am not as concerned about that, but if someone could help me find a better solution I would love to hear it.

Comment: Element with id `wait` is not present in the document. Please don't modify react directly you are asking  for errors like that

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't the span have an id of "wait"

Comment: It's probably not created yet

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of doing it:

```
const LoadingData = () => {
  // use state to control the dom
  const [dots, addDot] = useReducer((state) => (state + 1) % 6, 1);
  // set your intervals inside useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = window.setInterval(() => {
      addDot();
    }, 200);
    // remember to clear intervals
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [addDot]);

  return (
    <p>
      Loading<span id="wait">{".".repeat(dots)}</span>
    </p>
  );
};
```

[live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-hill-rrl5z1?file=/src/App.js:191-535)